# SOLR - Double search by one field with two sortings

Tags: solr, lucene

We have an upcoming date (upcomingDate fireld) of any event in solr docs. And we need to get results with events in ASC sorting from now to future (right direction) and events in DESC sorting from now to past (left direction). How we can make this in one query?

For example:

[image]

Results: NEADH

Answer (score 1):

Try the following sort query

`if(gte(ms(upcomingDate,NOW),0),ms(upcomingDate,NOW),sum(ms(NOW,upcomingDate),4125333600000)) asc`

Everything that is greater or equal than the present will be sorted naturally in ascending manner (`N E A` in the problem description drawing).
On the other hand, everything that is less than the present will be substracted from NOW and added to the millis corresponding to a date far in the future (i've used year 2100 for this sample code). In this manner you can achieve descending ordering for the past dates (`D H` in the problem description drawing).

So alltogether : `N  E A D H`

If somebody wants to try this query on `techproducts` collection delivered with the Solr distribution:
`if(gte(ms(manufacturedate_dt,2006-02-13T15:26:36Z),0),ms(manufacturedate_dt,2006-02-13T15:26:36Z),sum(ms(2006-02-13T15:26:36Z,manufacturedate_dt),4125333600000)) asc`

Comment: I tried this and got "can not sort on multivalued field: if(gte(ms(upcomingDate,NOW),0),ms(upcomingDate,NOW),sum(ms(NOW,upcomingDate),4125333600000))"

Comment: [Dimka](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4486743/dimka) please have a look at the [Solr Common Query Parameter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters) page. There you can see "Sorting can be done on the "score" of the document, or on any multiValued="false" indexed="true" field provided that field is either non-tokenized (ie: has no Analyzer) or uses an Analyzer that only produces a single Term (ie: uses the KeywordTokenizer) " . Try changing the type of your 'upcomingDate' field to be simple valued.

Comment: if i use simple operations for my date field (like ms(upcomingDate,NOW) or sum(ms(N‌​OW,upcomingDate)) - all is fine but if i paste part with gte(ms(upcomingDate,NOW),0) - i get this error

Comment: Btw in schema i have for date type="date" indexed="true" stored="true".
And one question - how system knows what field use for sorting?

Comment: [Dimka](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4486743/dimka) could you please post the error ? In your last comment you've mentioned : "i get this error" . Regarding the question about the sorting, all the fields of type date can be used for sorting. Solr will decide, based on your `sort` query paramter, which field(s) is/are taken into account.